# Git under Windows - Cannot launch external diff tool

Tags: git, difftool

I have a problem with launching meld tool for seeing diff.
In my .gitconfig i have:

```
[diff]
   tool = meld
```

and 'meld' is present in environment path (i can run it just by typing 'meld' in command prompt).
Reading lot of tuts how to configure difftool and it looks like this should be enough. But when typing `git difftool` i'm getting this error:

```
error: cannot spawn git-difftool--helper: No such file or directory
external diff died, stopping at initial.txt.
```

(initial.txt i'ts changed file that i want to diff)

Help, Please

Comment: did you try specifying full PATH to executable?

Comment: Yes, it was the first way that i've passed, with the same result ;/

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this problem?